# How to manage Places Menu in Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: ubuntu

A bit embarrassing as I thought I knew how to use Ubuntu until I stumble on a basic task!

I have named a connection I added to the bookmarks on the Places menu incorrectly and I have no idea how to edit it!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open nautilus, the Gnome file manager, then choose `Bookmarks`->`Edit bookmarks` from the menu. (In my German Gnome, it's `Lesezeichen`->`Lesezeichen bearbeiten`)

Shortcut is `Ctrl-B`.